# SELECT CONVERT_TZ command isn't affecting MySql server timezone

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, timezone

i'm on a shared unix server.

it has the default time zone `-06:00:00`

as per `MySQL Manual` i'm trying to set my timezone by executing the following command:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','-06:00','+07:00');
```

the command is being executed but it's not affecting the timezone. what's wrong with the server or my `SQL` command?

thanks,

Comment: I see nothing in the manual that suggests that `CONVERT_TZ()` can be used to *set* the time zone for the following queries. As the name says, it converts a datetime value from one zone to another. Nothing more. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: @Pekka 웃 yes, but the command isn't converting the default timezone with mine.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Can you clarify?

Comment: i want to convert server timezone from `GMT` `'-06:00'` to `GMT` `'+07:00'` by executing that command. but the command isn't affecting the server timezone.

Comment: But why are you expecting it to affect the server timezone? It's not designed to do that. Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html for info on how mySQL handles this

Comment: @Pekka i'm expecting that as MySql 5.1 manual guides so.

Comment: Where does it guide so?

Comment: the reference url is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz , thanks

Comment: Yes, I linked to that, too. Where does it say that `CONVERT_TZ()` changes the server time zone?

Comment: i'm re-posting the url with anchored tag. just click it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz this command isn't converting `timezone` associated with valid `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Yes, as said, it's the same link I posted earlier. It says there, `converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting value.` That's what `CONVERT_TZ()` does. Nothing else. Why are you expecting it to change the server's default time zone?

Comment: it shows the converted result only but doesn't implement it. what's the necessity of it then? it even doesn't say that the conversion won't be implemented. i give you another reference link which indicates that the conversion shall be implemented.. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/how-to-convert-mysql-time

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is, maybe make an example? What result are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: can you give me a worthy reference about how can i change mysql server time or at least use a php function for storing time based on my preferred timezone like `Asia/bangkok` (an example)?

Comment: On a shared server, changing the time zone may be impossible. You'd have to work around it some other way then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on a shared unix server, so you probably don't want to change the time zone of the MySQL server (unless you want to mess up everybody else who is using it).

Check the documentation for CONVERT_TZ - it doesn't set the time zone, it converts a datetime from one time zone to another. It returns a datetime.

For your example, `SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','-06:00','+07:00');` correctly returns `2004-01-02 01:00:00`.

If you change your connection's time zone, that won't affect anything for other users, but it will allow all your transactions on your connection to take place with a different default time zone. Use:

```
SET time_zone = {timezone}; -- where {timezone} is the timezone you want to use
```

And see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html for the documentation

Comment: thanks for helpful info. unfortunately i didn't find any clean reference yet where it is said that on a shared server expected timezone should be set using per connection basis mysql query. many thanks again. i figured it out finally.

Comment: Thanks. You can see what time_zone is set to by saying "show variables like 'time_zone';". That will probably show you that the server is using the SYSTEM's idea of the time zone. To change the connection time zone, use "set time_zone = 'America/Chicago'", if you are in Chicago, of course. The string has to be a value found in mysql.time_zone_name.Name.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check the mysql server timezone

use below SQl query

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

if you want to change the timezone  you can simply try this

```
set @@global.time_zone = '+07:00'
```

This will change the timezone of mysql server.

Note: the change will be flushed if you restart the server, in that case you should fire above query again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: your command isn't backward server compatible. therefore it returns timezone as `SYSTEM`. moreover i don't have super privilege to execute the command `set @@global.time_zone = '+07:00'`  in my case `SELECT @ @system_time_zone` is compatible with my server for checking it's timezone. thanks,